# Joomla 3.x admin login error

Tags: php, cookies

I've moved my joomla site from subdomain to main domain and from then I cannot login to my admin panel. The following error message given:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isAdmin() on a non-object in
>   /home/x11igato/public_html/stage.navigator/plugins/authentication/cookie/cookie.php
>   on line 57

I've wrote this lines in cookie.php, but with this, stil cannot login. Error message:

> Warning Username and password do not match or you do not have an
>   account yet.

Although my username and password is ok and exists in DB

```
public function __construct(& $subject, $config = array()) {
    $this->app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $this->db = JFactory::getDBO();;
}
```

PS.
After more reseach I've found that in table #_extension, plugin "remember" was set to 0, I've changed it to 1. Still no success with login, error shown:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isAdmin() on a non-object in /home/x11igato/public_html/plugins/system/remember/remember.php on line 42

FYI in configuration.php the "live_site" variable is equal with an empty string.

Comment: you can see: http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php?topic=301172.0
and login phpmyadmin, check plugin user enable or not?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

A few of quick tips:

1. Clear Joomla caches (through your FTP client - remove any cache files in the cache folder).
2. Clear your browser's cache and cookies.
3. Clear Sessions in Joomla database.
4. Make sure the move of your site was complete and you didn't end up with any corrupted or missing files from the Joomla core. It will be good, if you still have a backup of your working site since it was in the subdomain, to restore it. The method you followed to move your site, can be part of your problem.
5. Following n3, above, you could restore this at your local computer to debug the issue more efficiently.
6. What could happen if you move it back to the subdomain?
7. Also there plenty of similar questions/answers in this site, that deal with getting back your admin access by resetting your password if that's the case, or suggesting various other tricks.
8. In any case, try to keep somewhere untouched that backup file/site that used to work fine.